# Susy Grid, The more I learn the more confused I am

Tags: sass, susy-compass

I'm very new in this whole concept of Grids, I'm very use to:

```
<header>
<div class="wrap"></div>
</header>

header{width:100;display:inline;min-height:120px;height:100%;}
.wrap{width:960px;display:block;margin:0 auto;padding:0;position:relative;}
```

Now With this new Heoric Try to learn Grids with susy I came with;

```
.den-100{
  @include span-columns(12);
}


    .den-1r { @include span-columns(1) ;}
    .den-2r { @include span-columns(2) ;}
    .den-3r { @include span-columns(3) ;}
    .den-4r { @include span-columns(4) ;}
    .den-5r { @include span-columns(5) ;}
    .den-6r { @include span-columns(6) ;}
    .den-7r { @include span-columns(7) ;}
    .den-8r { @include span-columns(8) ;}
    .den-9r { @include span-columns(9) ;}
    .den-10r{ @include span-columns(10);}
    .den-11r{ @include span-columns(11);}
    .den-12r{ @include span-columns(12);}

    .den-1c { @include isolate(1) ;}
    .den-2c { @include isolate(2) ;}
    .den-3c { @include isolate(3) ;}
    .den-4c { @include isolate(4) ;}
    .den-5c { @include isolate(5) ;}
    .den-6c { @include isolate(6) ;}
    .den-7c { @include isolate(7) ;}
    .den-8c { @include isolate(8) ;}
    .den-9c { @include isolate(9) ;}
    .den-10c{ @include isolate(10);}
    .den-11c{ @include isolate(11);}
    .den-12c{ @include isolate(12);}
```

so

I can do:

```
<header class="den-100">
<aside class="den-3c den-5r></aside>
<aside class="den-8c den-2r"></side>
</header>
```

And it really do the work as my previous workflow, but Now I'm confused , is this the correct way to SusyGrid?

What about the responsive?, Using breakpoints and display: block will be the correct way?

I'm going in a free ticket direct to the limbo. MayBe Susy Documentation is too complex  for me...

thanks

Comment: Susy is not designed to use as a class library — but it is designed to be flexible. So if it works for you, you're doing it right. I'm not sure what "r" and "c" mean to you, or what exactly you are trying to achieve. When it comes to breakpoints and responsive design, this class-library approach gets much more complex, and will be harder to implement. See http://susy.oddbird.net/demos/magic/ or search the web for Susy tutorials (there are plenty) to see how Susy is usually used.

Comment: Thanks for the Clarification , I suppose this learning curve will simplify in the next days ... and what I mean with "r" is ROW and "c" COLUMN .